# View and audit all App Scripts on GSuite domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

Is there a way for me to be able to view and audit all app scripts created in my gsuite domain being an admin, without it being shared with me? I know that I'm able to pull all files in drive using vault and I assume if the app script files were still in drive, I could probably have searched for them that way, but that doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Vault to search for the  Scripts projects. The GAS files will display this icon next to the script title https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_script_x16.png

You can use Vault to download it but it will be a json file, you can't preview the GAS JSON file but you can use the Drive API to import it to your own account, more info at [Import Google app script project from JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663198/import-google-app-script-project-from-json-file)

Comment: Would I be using Vault to search Drive for Scripts projects? I only see the search options for Mail, Drive, Groups, and Hangouts Chat.

Comment: Yes, you have to use the Drive search option which will display all files in their Drive including docs, sheets, Scripts, etc. At this time there is no option to make specific search for scripts files.